# Securing the PHP code from SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql, security, code-injection

I have a PHP site which has a lot of POST and GET variables.

For each of the POST and GET variables on every page I have added as follows:

If I needed only numbers in the [POST/GET] variable...

```
$post_q_time_post = preg_replace('~[^0-9]+~', '', $_POST["q_time_post"] );
```

If I needed Text / Numbers ..

```
$post_oldp = preg_replace('~[^a-zA-Z0-9]+~', '', $_POST['oldp'] );
```

And then used the stripped variable all over the page.

How secure is my site now? Is it possible to do SQL injection of any other PHP based attack now ? If so, what additional steps I should do ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's secure as not even having a login system..  Please use prepared statements. That's the way out..

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use prepared statement with parameterized queries.

Comment: @Akintunde I have a login system, a login page that sets a $_SESSION variables and then a function at the beginning of all the pages that checks for this $_SESSION and if not found it redirects to login page.

Comment: @FirstOne I have seen that page , but I have many queries over many pages it would take quite some time to change all. In the meantime I put up this as it was quicker and easier to implement. So my question is still.. am I secure? as some of my students love to play around.

Comment: You'd get more problems with this approach than from doing things _right_. Imagine a person uses a password that's changed by your function, and later you change that function in a way that now it returns a different value than before. If you're really worried about _security_, you already know the path. I'm sorry I can't vouch for the security of this method - as in not capable.

Comment: A sidenote, as said in the following question - [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) -, you're not always safe just because the is no quotation marks, for example. Take a query that assumes int: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE my_int_val = $val`. If $val is `0 or 1=1`, you have valid content that still got injected. Of course, this would fall into the first code of yours, but still, it's a risk.

Comment: @FirstOne Right now I manually create and give out number only passwords, but in the future if users create their own, I see your point. As for your second answer of "0 or 1=1" the "=" sign and the " " is also stripped off so now it becomes "0or11", would that be risky as well ? Thanks.